# How to create a contour temperature map within a specific contour of the bathymetric map in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have data for bathymetry of the studied area and made a contour map.
I also have data for sea water temperature at different depths. I made the maps for sea water temperatures at the 25m depth but it extrapolates the values to the shores and beyond.
I am looking at the ways to limit the temperature data to the defined bathymetric contours based on my bathymetric data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the short [Tour]. You haven't provided much in the way of details about the layers involved (nane data format, available attributes,...), making any Answers extremely vague.(or potentially way off target). Please [Edit] the Question to provide details and an indication of what you have tried. Using a mask after interpolation seems a promising approach.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.